# how to speed up manipulate and contourplot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I know that [`ListAnimate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html) perform well. But if we have parameters in the formula.

For example:

```
Manipulate[Visualization`Core`ContourPlot[
EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {a, 0}] EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {-a, 0}] == b^2
, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
, {{b, 1}, 0, 5}, {{a, 1}, 0, 5}]
```

How to make the performance better?

**Add explanations:**

[image]

it's clear that when I drag the slider, the curve doesn't smooth. So is there any method to make it smooth?

Comment: Which version are you using as this is instantly responsive in 12.0?  As an aside, you do not need ``Visualization`Core` ``     prefix on `ContourPlot`. Just `ContourPlot` will do.

Comment: @Edmund  11.3 , since I found that undocumented function is faster in some way.

Comment: Just tried it in 11.3 and it is also instantly responsive. You could try restarting your kernel. As it stands the issue is not reproducible.

Comment: tried the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in  `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @Edmund  I can reproduce the results shown.  As long as the left mouse button is held down, the curve continues to look like a polygon.  However, `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` almost completely eliminates the  problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Ah, the edit with the inclusion of the gif explains what the OP was concerned with. The answer is in kglr's comment.

Comment: This is by design. Read up on `Manipulate`. Start with http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html and look for `ControlActive`.